# Invalid regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to find out if a string contains css code with this expression:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('\s(?[a-zA-Z-]+)\s[:]{1}\s*(?[a-zA-Z0-9\s.#]+)[;]{1}');
```

But I get "invalid regular expression" error on the line above...

What's wrong with it?

found the regex here: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-regular-expressions-for-efficient-web-development

It's for PHP but it should work in javascript too, right?

Comment: I would suggest avoiding that website.  Taking coding advice from a cat is probably a bad idea in general.

Comment: While CSS isn't a terribly complex language, it is probably a bit too complex to be detected reliably with a single regex. My guess is that there are better ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That regular expression is very bad and I would avoid its source in the future. That said, I cleaned it up a bit and got the following result:

```
var pattern = /\s(?:[a-zA-Z-]+)\s*:\s*(?:[^;\n\r]+);/;
```

this matches something that looks like css, for example:

```
background-color: red;
```

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAeYE/) to prove it, though I'd recommend to find a different solution to your problem. This is a very simple regex and it's not save to say that it is reliable.

Answer (score 3):

What are the `?` at the start of the two `[a-zA-z-]` blocks for?  They look wrong to me.

The `?` is unfortunately somewhat overload in regexp syntax, it can have three different meanings that I know of, and none of them match what I see in your example.

Also, your `\s` sequences need the backslash escaping because this is a string - they should look like `\\s`.  To avoid escaping, just use the `/.../` syntax instead of `new Regexp("...")`.

That said, even that is insufficient - the regexp still produces an `Invalid Group` error in Chrome, probably related to the `{1}` sequences.

Comment: @JamWaffles it wasn't a comment because it was the first potential problem I spotted - i.e. an answer.

Comment: The site the regex was gotten from says `<\?[php]*([^\?>]*)\?>` can be used to match php code. I can only assume the CSS regex is just as bad.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the quotes with `/` (slashes):

```
var pattern = /\s([a-zA-Z-]+)\s[:]{1}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\s.#]+)[;]{1}/;
```

You also don't need the `new RegExp()` part either, which is why it's been removed; instead of using a quote or double quote to denote a *string*, JavaScript uses a slash `/` to denote a regular expression, which isn't a normal string.

Comment: You seem to have replaced the quotes with forward slashes `/`

Comment: You don't need `new RegExp` when you are using a regex literal. Use either `new RegExp("...")` or `/.../` (the `...` representing whatever regex you want, of course.

Comment: @Arjan I was too hasty in writing my answer. I edited it soon afterwards.

Comment: @benekastah Thanks. I haven't done JS Regex in a while, so I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: and this is still incorrect - try actually testing it!  It produces an `Invalid group` error in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The `?`'s are messing it up. I'm not sure what they are for.

`/\s[a-zA-Z\-]+\s*:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9\s.#]+;/`

worked for me (as far as compiling. I didn't test to see if it properly detected a CSS string).

Comment: and would you have spotted that if I hadn't already put that in my answer?

Comment: I spotted it at around the same time. I thought it was valuable that I had a working regex. If an additional answer is inappropriate, I would be happy to add my regex to yours.

Comment: no, that's ok - at least yours compiles, even if it doesn't necessarily do the same as the broken one the OP posted.